# How to handle Web application logic and database concurrency?

Tags: web, concurrency, race-condition, database-concurrency

Let's say I have a table called `items`. User of my webapp can delete row of the `items` table, but I don't want to let the table empty.

So currently I have code like this in my application:

```
if (itemsCount() <= 1) {
  don't delete;
}
else {
  delete;
}
```

But I realize this code is vulnerable to concurrency problem. For example if currently the size of `items` is 2, and there are two thread executing this code at almost the exact same time, the table might become empty.

I think this problem is pretty common for people writing webapps. People should've already solved it. What are the available solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution is to use a Transaction Manager. In your case, the Transaction Manager would coordinate the thread execution to make sure that only one thread at a time access and updates the table.

You didn't mention which language and which kind of environment you are using, but assuming Java and JEE, transaction management is quite easy. Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I use Java, besides wrapping it in a transaction, do I still need to synchronize that block of code?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to do that.